# Why is there a huge gap on the grid I created?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Im learning how to use grid container and so far i created a grid with 2 images on top and 2 on the bottom and then 1 to the left side that stretches vertically. I have the grid how i want it, however i cannot get rid of the huge gap in between each image. I tried adjusting the grid gap and even got rid of it but it does not change nothing at all. How can i fix this problem?

Thanks

```css
.PopDestination-Header{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 100px;
}
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);

  }
  .grid-item-1 {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 1/3;
  }
  .grid-item-2 {
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 1/2;
  }
  .grid-item-3 {
    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 1/2;
  }
  .grid-item-4 {
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 3/4;
  }
  .grid-item-5 {
    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 3/4;
  }
```

```html
<section class="PopularDestination">
        <div class="PopDestination-Header">
            <h1>Popular Destination</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container">
           <div class="grid-item-1"><img src ="Images/meric-dagli-CK_MX9mBGRo-unsplash.jpg" height="700" width="350"></div>
           <div class="grid-item-2"><img src ="Images/doug-watanabe-9uiUGnGeeUo-unsplash.jpg" height="350" width="500"></div>
           <div class="grid-item-3"><img src ="Images/ryan-stone-VnZMKbXrA0I-unsplash.jpg" height="350" width="500"></div>
           <div class="grid-item-4"><img src ="Images/clay-elliot-3xJAVC07AYk-unsplash.jpg" height="350" width="500"></div>
           <div class="grid-item-5"><img src ="Images/mike-dierken-KmA5OdUkAj8-unsplash.jpg" height="350" width="500"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

[image]

Comment: You are telling your grid to take up all available free space. Do you not want it to do that?

Comment: the gaps are the images not filling up the space in the grid, because their width and height are smaller than the dimensions set for the grid column and rows

Comment: I want all the images to be close to each other. I tried resizing the images so they can be the same dimensions. Sorry for the confusion guys, im still learning how to work with grids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.grid-item-4 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  /* grid-row: 3/4; */
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.grid-item-5 {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  /* grid-row: 3/4; */
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be useful

Comment: Yes of course, thanks for the tip. I'm new here, I still don't know how to answer correctly. ))

Answer (score 2):

I edited your code like below. I hope it works for you. While running code snippet please make full screen for right view.

```css
.PopDestination-Header{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px;
}
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-item-1 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/4;
}
.grid-item-2 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
.grid-item-3 {
  grid-column: 3/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
.grid-item-4 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/2;
}
.grid-item-5 {
  grid-column: 3/3;
  grid-row: 2/2;
}
```

```html
<section class="PopularDestination">
    <div class="PopDestination-Header">
        <h1>Popular Destination</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-container">
       <div class="grid-item-1"><img src ="https://picsum.photos/211" height="700" width="350"></div>
       <div class="grid-item-2"><img src ="https://picsum.photos/222" height="350" width="500"></div>
       <div class="grid-item-3"><img src ="https://picsum.photos/256" height="350" width="500"></div>
       <div class="grid-item-4"><img src ="https://picsum.photos/247" height="350" width="500"></div>
       <div class="grid-item-5"><img src ="https://picsum.photos/265" height="350" width="500"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Gaps columns and rows looks like this in chrome browser:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```css
.grid-container {
  max-width: min-content;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

Comment: Almost Worked! It closed the gap vertically but there's still a gap horizontally